# How to run QucsStudio at the command line?

Tags: analysis, circuit

I am trying to run QucsStudio from a command line.

I am using this line

```
"C:\Programs1\QucsStudio\bin\qucs.exe" -n -i  "Klopfenstein_taper_OK.sch" -o "Klopfenstein_taper_OK.net"
```

Using QucsStudio ver. 4.3.1.

When I run the above line, QucsStudio opens and load the sch file. No analysis though.
I found no documentation to show how to run the analysis in batch mode (command lien)

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using command prompt or powershell?

Comment: I am using command prompt